# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when dispatching action from ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm subscribing to `ngrx` store in the constructor of my `AppComponent`:

```
export class AppComponent {
    submenuItems: Observable<Array<INavigationBarItem>>;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
        this.submenuItems = this.store.select<Array<INavigationBarItem>>((state: AppState) => state.submenu.items);
    }
}
```

Then, I'm dispatching an action in my other component's `ngOnInit` method, like this:

```
export class SearchPageComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.store.dispatch(new SubmenuAction([
            { title: 'Search', isActive: true },
            { title: 'New Group' }
        ]));
    }
}
```

And the result of this interaction is the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` exception. If I move that `dispatch` call to the constructor of my child component, then no error is thrown, but I'm wondering if that's only by chance. Also I don't think putting this inside constructor body is a good idea.

Each of my components will need to have this `store.dispatch` call - as you can see, its purpose is to produce a submenu data which will be different from page to page. How to get around this exception?

Comment: Did you try implementing `OnInit` in your `AppComponent` and then subscribing to the `ngrx` store inside `ngOnInit() {}`?  Is there a special need to do it inside the constructor? As far as I understand, doing business logic inside the constructor is not always best practice, you should only use it for DI purposes

Comment: what is the error description? you may want to read this article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: @OsmanCea - yes, I tried that and the error was the same.

Comment: I just had the same problem today... Moving the select into the constructor solved it but it's obviously not something I want to do, just temporary. Pretty sure it's a bug...

Comment: @Maxime - you mean "moving dispatch into constructor", right? :)

Comment: Oh I just checked what it was exactly, and I'm using FlexLayout. It gives me an observable that returns the screen size. In there, I set a class variable to that size. If I do that into ngOnInit, it crashes. Into the constructor it's fine...

Comment: I ran into the same problem, changing the store subscribe to the constructor didn't change anything!!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem a couple of times, and figured it would be a problem with Angular zone management. What I did is more like a hack, but maybe it solves your problem too:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.store.dispatch(new SubmenuAction([
        { title: 'Search', isActive: true },
        { title: 'New Group' }
    ])), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Moving the dispatch calls onto constructor from ngOnInit worked for me.

```
export class SearchPageComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { 
 this.store.dispatch(new SubmenuAction([
        { title: 'Search', isActive: true },
        { title: 'New Group' }
    ]));
}

    ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```